# How do I show that if $R=\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}$ and $M=\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}$ then $M$ is a projective $R$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, commutative-algebra, modules

> **Projective Module** Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ an $R$-module. We say that $M$ is projective if $Hom(M,-)$ is exact.

> Let $R=\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}$ and take $M=\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}$. Using the above definition I want to show that $M$ is projective. I know there are other way of showing it but I would like to practice a bit with exact sequences.

My idea was the following:

Let $A,B,C$ be $R$-modules and consider the short exact sequence $$0\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} A\stackrel{g}{\rightarrow} B\stackrel{h}{\rightarrow} C\stackrel{j}{\rightarrow} 0$$ Applying $Hom(M,-)$ gives me the sequence $$0\stackrel{\bar f}{\rightarrow} Hom(M,A)\stackrel{\bar g}{\rightarrow} Hom(M,B)\stackrel{\bar h}{\rightarrow} Hom(M,C)\stackrel{\bar j}{\rightarrow} 0$$Now I only need to check if $\bar g$ is injective and $\bar h$ is surjective. Let me remark that $$\bar g:Hom(M,A)\rightarrow Hom(M,B),~~~(\phi:M\rightarrow A)\mapsto g\circ \phi$$ Therefore $\ker(\bar g)=\{\phi\in Hom(M,A):g\circ \phi=0\}=\{\phi\in \ker(g)\}=\{0\}$ hence $\bar g$ is injective.

Now let us check if $\bar h$ is surjective. Let $\psi\in Hom(M,C)$ . I only need to find a map $\sigma$ in $Hom(M,B)$ such that for all $m\in M$ $\bar h(\sigma(m))=\psi(m)$.

Here I somehow get stuck. I know that using the surjectivity of $h$ gives me that there exists $b\in B$ such that $h(b)=\psi(m)$. But I somehow don't se how to conclude.

Could maybe someone tell me if the injectivity part is correct and also how do I proceed in the subjectivity part?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Might also be a good exercise to prove it a different way than you are currently:  prove that an $R$ module is projective iff it's a summand of a free $R$ module.  Then in your case, $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z2\mathbb Z\cong \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ (all as modules over $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$) establishes $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ is a summand.

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:

1. Hom is left exact so you just have to check that $\overline h$ is surjective.
2. So far you haven't used anything about the particular module $M$ or the ring $R$.
3. Prove that an element of Hom$(M, N)$ is determined by choosing an element $n \in N$ such that $3 \cdot n = 0$.

Comment: Sorry I don't get the 3. point. What do you mean? I know that $\bar h(\sigma(m))=h(b)$ for some $b\in B$.

Comment: I mean $\sigma \in Hom(M,B)$ is a map $\sigma:\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}\rightarrow B$  and the elements in the domain are $M=\{\bar 0,\bar 1,\bar 2\}$. I don't see why I need to pick $b\in B$ and look at $3\cdot b=0$?

Comment: A homomorphism from $B$ is determined by where it maps $1$.